# Calculation of the norm of linear combinitation of two states on a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Suppose $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are two states on $A$. If $\rho_1=\rho_2$, we have $\|\rho_1+i\rho_2\|=\sqrt{2}$.

If we have $\|\rho_1+i\rho_2\|=\sqrt{2}$, can we conclude that $\rho_1=\rho_2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is YES.
Consider any $a\in A$ with $0\le a\le 1$ and
put $\alpha:=(\rho_1+i\rho_2)(a)$ and $\beta:=(\rho_1+i\rho_2)(1-a)=(1+i)-\alpha$.
Then $x:=(\bar{\alpha}/|\alpha|)a+(\bar{\beta}/|\beta|)(1-a)$ has norm at most $1$ and so
$$|1+i|\geq|(\rho_1+i\rho_2)(x)|=|\alpha|+|(1+i)-\alpha|.$$
Hence $\alpha$ must be on the line connecting $0$ and $1+i$, that is to say,
$\rho_1(a)=\rho_2(a)$.